# Problema con bucle for en JS: por que el iterador siempre apunta al ultimo elemento del arreglo?

Tags: javascript, html, css

-Buenas, tengo un problema al cual ya encontre la solucion, ahora solo me pregunto: *por que surge este problema* ...

```js
const title__element = document.getElementsByClassName("initial__title")[0];
const titleLetterClassName = "title__letter"
const overTitleLetterClassName = "title__letter__overed"

for (letter of title__element.innerText) {
    let new_letter = document.createElement("span");
    new_letter.innerText = letter;
    new_letter.classList.add(titleLetterClassName)
    title__element.appendChild(new_letter);
}
title__element.removeChild(title__element.childNodes[0]);
for (child of title__element.children){
    child.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
        console.log(child);
        child.classList.add(overTitleLetterClassName);
    })
    child.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
        console.log(child);
        child.classList.remove(overTitleLetterClassName);
    })
}
```

```css
#inicio{
    height: 100vh;
    width : 100vw;
    background-color : #f00;
}
.initial__title{
    padding : 30px;
}
.title__letter{
    cursor : pointer;
    transition : transform .5s;
}


.title__letter__overed{
    transform : scale(1.4,1.4 );
}

.initial__title{
    background-color : #0f0;
    display : inline;
    position : relative;
    left : 40vw;
    top : 20vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="initial__title">Hola</h1>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Si ven los resultados en una consola, veran que todos los `eventListeners` se aplicaron sobre el ultimo elemento del arreglo... La primera pregunta seria: ***por que `child` (en el segundo bucle) siempre apunta al ultimo elemento del arreglo?*** La solucion a este problema seria declarar la variable con `let` ...

```
const title__element = document.getElementsByClassName("initial__title")[0];
const titleLetterClassName = "title__letter"
const overTitleLetterClassName = "title__letter__overed"

for (letter of title__element.innerText) {
    let new_letter = document.createElement("span");
    new_letter.innerText = letter;
    new_letter.classList.add(titleLetterClassName)
    title__element.appendChild(new_letter);
}
title__element.removeChild(title__element.childNodes[0]);
for (/*  aca  ----> */  let child of title__element.children){
    child.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
        console.log(child);
        child.classList.add(overTitleLetterClassName);
    })
    child.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
        console.log(child);
        child.classList.remove(overTitleLetterClassName);
    })
}
```

Y la segunda pregunta (a la cual no he encontrado solucion) es : ***por que el `transform : scale()` no funciona?***

Answer (score 3):

Ya solucionaste el problema de la variable dentro del ciclo y solo queda aplicar los estilos CSS.

De acuerdo a la especificación CSS, las transformaciones solo aplican a [elementos transformables](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element) que, en tu caso, no aplica a `span` por ser elemento en línea.

Es suficiente con cambiar a un modelo de caja, como bloque en línea con `display: inline-block` y, además, no necesitas Javascript para aplicar o remover una clase cuando el mouse entra o sale. Con usar el pseudoselector [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) en la clase original ya logras el efecto deseado.

```js
const title__element = document.getElementsByClassName("initial__title")[0];
const titleLetterClassName = "title__letter"
const overTitleLetterClassName = "title__letter__overed"

for (letter of title__element.innerText) {
    let new_letter = document.createElement("span");
    new_letter.innerText = letter;
    new_letter.classList.add(titleLetterClassName)
    title__element.appendChild(new_letter);
}
title__element.removeChild(title__element.childNodes[0]);
/* *** Descomenta este bloque si quieres hacerlo por Javascript
for(let child of title__element.children){
    child.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
        console.log(child);
        child.classList.add(overTitleLetterClassName);
    })
    child.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
        console.log(child);
        child.classList.remove(overTitleLetterClassName);
    })
}
*/
```

```css
#inicio{
    height: 100vh;
    width : 100vw;
    background-color : #f00;
}
.initial__title{
    padding : 30px;
}
.title__letter{
    /* Debe mostrarse como bloque en línea */
    display: inline-block;
    cursor : pointer;
    transition : transform .5s;
}

/* Usar pseudoselector para no tener que modificar clases */
/* Cambia al nombre de clase que tenías si quieres hacerlo por Javascript */
.title__letter:hover{
    transform : scale(1.4,1.4 );
}

.initial__title{
    background-color : #0f0;
    display : inline;
    position : relative;
    left : 40vw;
    top : 20vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="initial__title">Hola</h1>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```